# Github repository without node_modules

Tags: node.js, github, node-modules

I upload the project to github without the node_modules directory. When other people reclone the repository from github, they will have "Cannot find module.." error. What should I do to let others auto download the corresponding modules?

Thanks for everyone's help, I forgot to run "npm install".

Comment: If you upload your package.json file, then they should be running `npm install` to get all dependencies.

Comment: add package.json to the repository and let others manage dependencies (node_modules) through npm

Comment: Dependent packages should be in the `packages.json` in your module and that should be in github.  Then, when they install your module, NPM will automatically get the required other packages.

Comment: Add: Not committing `node_modules` + adding it to `.gitigonre` + committing `package.json` and `package-lock.json` is a good idea. `npm install` will take care of it when one clones it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if there is package.json in your repositoy. Whoever is cloning this repository they just install npm, Like **npm install**.

Second thing whoever is installing required packages , He must use **--save** so it will add and save that package to package.json. So simply **npm install** will work for them.
If you don't use **--save** command the other person who is cloning that repository , He must add that package explicitly by typing **npm install "package name"** after npm is installed.